# Parsing date format of mmm dd yyyy to excel date format

Tags: excel, date

We use a booking system at work that exports reports where the date is entered in the format mmm dd yyyy (for example "Jun 01 2018"). Excel does not recognise this and the usual date formatting formulas can't touch it.

Is there a way to parse this using a formula so I can simply dump this export into a spreadsheet so I can perform quick analysis on booking behaviour.

I have not been able to find a solution to this online for this specific issue in Excel.

Thanks.

Comment: Text-to-Columns, Fixed Width, one column only, MDY, Finish.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I hadn't thought of [@Jeeped's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788134/parsing-date-format-of-mmm-dd-yyyy-to-excel-date-format#comment90533676_51788134), using Text-to-Columns. I like it; that's probably the quickest way if you have a list of dates that need to be converted ad-hoc.

If you need a worksheet formula to do the conversion on an "ongoing" basis, this formula will also do the trick:

```
=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",", ",2))
```

...where the string containing the date in `MMM DD YYYY` format is in cell `A1`.

Basically, Excel is picky about a comma.

Excel doesn't recognize `Aug 08 2018` as a date, but it *does* recognize `Aug 08, 2018` as a date.

This formula replaces the second space with a comma+space, and then `DATEVALUE` will recognize it as a date.

As usual, the date will be returned as a [serial number](https://www.lifewire.com/serial-number-serial-date-3123991), so then you can format the cell as a date with the **Format Cells** dialog: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> or (Right Click) > Format Cells.

---

Further to [@Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped)'s method in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51788134/parsing-date-format-of-mmm-dd-yyyy-to-excel-date-format#comment90533676_51788134), this is how to do the same thing using *Text-to-Columns:*

[image]

1. Select (highlight) the cells to "convert"
2. on the **Data** tab of the ribbon, click **Text to Columns**
3. Choose **Fixed Width** (if not already selected), then click <kbd>Next</kbd>
4. Double-click each *break line* (if there are any), then click <kbd>Next</kbd>
5. Choose **Date** and then in the drop-down, choose `MDY`
6. Click <kbd>Finish</kbd>

---

### More Information:

- Office Support : [**`DATEVALUE` function**](https://support.office.com/article/datevalue-function-df8b07d4-7761-4a93-bc33-b7471bbff252)
- Office Support : [**`SUBSTITUTE` function**](https://support.office.com/article/substitute-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332)
- Office Support : [**Split text into different columns with the Text to Columns Wizard**](https://support.office.com/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7)
- ExcelTrainer : [**Converting Date Format Using Text To Columns**](https://theexceltrainer.co.uk/converting-date-format-using-text-to-columns/)

Comment: That's great! Yes, I would have used text to column if it was a one off, but really wanted a solution that supported dumping booking data into a spreadsheet on a monthly basis and the formulas all being there to analyse. This answers my query,

Answer (score 0):

This should be `=DATEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",", ",3))` in case your data is 'mmm d yyyy' when the day of the month < 10

This works for all days of the month regardless of if the day of the month is zero filled